# for loop in coffeescript promise

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, coffeescript

I've a coffeescript where I wish to add 100 legal holds to an object.

To add one I do the following:

```
  .then (data) =>
      s3.addLegalHold({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: 'foo',
        RetentionLegalHoldId: 'holdid'
      }).promise()
```

To add 100 I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  .then (data) =>
    for i in [0 .. 99]
      console.log('count: ' + i)
      s3.addLegalHold({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: 'foo',
        RetentionLegalHoldId: 'holdid' + i
      }).promise()
```

My `console.log('count: ' + i)` goes up to 99 but I can only ever see one legal hold when the test is complete. I giess it's something to do with the promise but I'm not sure. Ho do I do this?

Comment: I think there might be a problem that your first example is returning a promise, while the second is returning an array of promises. Could you show the code which comes after this block? what are you doing with the legal holds once the promise fulfills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.then (data) =>
  promises = []
  for i in [0 .. 99]
    promises.push(s3.addLegalHold({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: 'foo',
      RetentionLegalHoldId: 'holdid' + i
    }).promise())
  return Promise.all(promises)
```

The crucial difference is `Promise.all` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)). It takes an array of promises (in your case, 100 promises), waits for all of them to resolve, then resolves itself.

Comment: I ran that code several times and found it was adding between 80 and 90 legal holds each time. I tried moving `promises = []` and it works as I want. this is what it now looks like:

`.then (data) =>
        promises = []
        for i in [0 .. 99]
          promises.push(s3.addLegalHold({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: 'foo',
            RetentionLegalHoldId: 'holdid' + i
          }).promise())
        return Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: Yes, if the answer has not been edited in a couple of hours or so, then I'll do it myself.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks for the warning. I'll spare you of the waiting – just edit if you can improve it! :-)

Comment: Hi Fabian, done. Just the same movement of `promises = []` that runnerpaul already indicated.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on the array of promises that your loop evaluates to:

```
  .then (data) =>
    Promise.all( for i in [0 ... 100]
      console.log ('count: ' + i)
      s3.addLegalHold {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: 'foo',
        RetentionLegalHoldId: 'holdid' + i
      }
      .promise() )
```

This will get you a promise for an array of the results.

Comment: Does coffeesript's `for ... in ...` return array?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes, everything is an expression in CoffeeScript.

Comment: How odd. I suppose one gets used to it.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Not that I ever used CoffeeScript myself, but it's a distinct feature and I guess you'd want to use it, if you are still using CoffeeScript instead of ES6+. Probably it was more important back in the day when browser support for ES5 `map` was still low.